# Show active parent's listed children when viewing it children

Tags: templating

When I view a entry that's belong to a small group of children with a parent assigned. When I view the child, I want to display list all children that the child assigned to?

Is there anyway to achieve this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `getSiblings()` method. This will return all sibling entries for the current entry. You can also use `getParent()` to get the parent entry and `getChildren()` to get the entries child entries.

An example implementation is below:

```
{% set siblings = entry.getSiblings() %}
{% set parent = entry.getParent() %}
{% set children = entry.getChildren() %}

{% if parent|length %}
  <h2>Parent</h2>
  <p>{{ parent.title }}</p>
{% endif %}

{% if siblings|length %}
  <h2>Siblings</h2>
  {% for entry in siblings %}
    <p>{{ entry.title }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{% if children|length %}
  <h2>Children</h2>
  {% for entry in children %}
    <p>{{ entry.title }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

More info on these methods can be found in the [EntryModel documentation](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#getSiblings).